# Slice of impact analysis plugin frama-C

Tags: frama-c

The impact analysis plugin has a method slice which slices the given statement according to the impact analysis. 
Is it like the slicing plugin where we create project then we choose the slicing zone and after adding this zone to the request? How could i print the result of this impact analysis slice?

Comment: Is there a level like the slicing plugin or it is completly static?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `Db.Impact.slice` has actually no real link to the `Impact` plugin. It simply computes a slicing request on the given list of statements, without calling `Impact` anywhere. As you noticed, you can already build this request from the API of `Slicing`, while `Db.Impact.Stmt` is not customizable.

(This function `slice` should be internal to `Impact`. It is used in the GUI when the user has selected the option *Slicing after impact*. We will remove it in the next release to lift this ambiguity.)

Comment: Ah! ok! indeed, it was a bit ambiguous. When i called Db.Impact.slice, it built a project named "impact slicing" which only computes a slicing request  on the given list of statements